# Android GoogleMaps not loading

Tags: java, android, maps

I am trying to get google maps to work on my android app but for some reason it will not load. I have done everything on the google documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

At this point I have no idea what is going on.
Here is the code I have written so far

```
   package com.example.postplay;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MapActive extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    double lat;
    double lan;
    boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_active);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_active, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.postplay"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.postplay.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.postplay.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.postplay.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-fenter code hereilter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.postplay.AddGame"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_game" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="~HIDDEN~" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.postplay.MapActive"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_active" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

When I run the app on my device I just get a blank screen saying

" The date on the device appears to be incorrect. Please check the date on the device."

Any help would be much appreciated

here are my log messages

01-04 17:27:36.579: W/ResourceType(20372): Failure getting entry for 0x01080a03 (t=7 e=2563) in package 0 (error -75)
01-04 17:27:36.689: D/libEGL(20372): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
01-04 17:27:36.729: D/libEGL(20372): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
01-04 17:27:36.749: D/libEGL(20372): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
01-04 17:27:36.839: D/OpenGLRenderer(20372): Enabling debug mode 0
01-04 17:27:51.079: I/dalvikvm(20372): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
01-04 17:27:51.079: D/dalvikvm(20372): Rejecting registerization due to and-int/lit16 v0, v5, (#128)
01-04 17:27:51.089: I/dalvikvm(20372): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
01-04 17:27:51.089: D/dalvikvm(20372): Rejecting registerization due to and-int/lit16 v0, v5, (#128)
01-04 17:27:51.239: W/ResourceType(20372): Failure getting entry for 0x01080a03 (t=7 e=2563) in package 0 (error -75)
01-04 17:27:51.239: D/dalvikvm(20372): Rejecting registerization due to div-int/lit8 v0, v3, (#2)
01-04 17:27:51.299: D/dalvikvm(20372): Rejecting registerization due to div-int/lit8 v0, v3, (#2)
01-04 17:27:51.309: D/dalvikvm(20372): Rejecting registerization due to div-int/lit8 v0, v3, (#2)
01-04 17:27:51.689: I/dalvikvm(20372): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
01-04 17:27:51.689: I/dalvikvm(20372): Total arena pages for JIT: 14
01-04 17:27:51.689: I/dalvikvm(20372): Total arena pages for JIT: 15
01-04 17:27:51.689: I/dalvikvm(20372): Total arena pages for JIT: 16
01-04 17:27:51.689: I/dalvikvm(20372): Total arena pages for JIT: 17

Comment: Have you checked the date on the device?

Comment: Where is your error log?

Comment: you don't need this `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

Comment: I just added my log messages. Why don't I need <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

Comment: @user3404290 check the link that you posted you will know. also it is better to check the availability of google play services before initializing the map object